# Close multi line prompt in Spyder

Tags: python, input, spyder

How on earth does one close the multi-line input in the Spyder console for python? I can't find any solution and its slowly driving me insane.

```
In [2]:twenty_test.data
   ...:
   ...:
   ...:
```

Does anyone know how I can terminate this input?

Comment: Afraid not, I've tried escape characters, double linefeed, all the normal keyboard interrupts... I simply cannot escape the input block.

Comment: I don't understand your example. How is that an input block? How did you get multiple lines? Can you come up with a simple reproducible example so we can play along at home?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really explain my problem very well. Normally typing something into the Spyder Console will result in it being executed. Sometimes, and apparently, randomly, the console simply won't execute the line and will just add another line below.

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of the problem. It occurred while I was working on some fairly simple machine learning code. As you can see, I simply can't end the console input line on the right. http://postimg.org/image/sr6id5dht/

Comment: This is [a bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2696). Sounds like they have a fix which will be released in v3.0 this month.

Answer (score 6):

Hitting [shift] + [Enter] will close the multi-line editing and execute any entered code.

Just in case anyone else is looking for this, I struggled to turn on multi-line editing and couldn't find that question posted and answered.

Hitting [ctrl] + [Enter] will start multi-line editing

Comment: thank you! truly and honestly, best answer on the web

Answer (score 1):

multiple line input in spyder is terminated with a ";"
Just place a semi-colon at the end of your last line of input.